# Carthageでバイナリーインストールのみサポートということがなぜ起こるのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, carthage

https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxKeyboard

のREADMEには、

> With Carthage, RxKeyboard only supports binary installation:

Carthageの場合、バイナリーインストールのみサポートとあります。

Carthageの仕組みをあまり把握していないのですが、

```
$ carthage update --platform ios --cache-builds --no-use-binaries
```

とした場合、
`--cache-builds`の意味は`ビルド済みのライブラリはスキップ`
`--no-use-binaries`の意味は`そうでないライブラリはソースからコンパイル`
と考えました。

ここで疑問なのですが、バイナリーインストールのみサポートとはどういうことなのでしょうか？
なぜGitHubにソースコードがあるにもかかわらず、バイナリーを私達のローカルマシーンで作り出すことができないのでしょうか？

今回の質問は、どちらかというと`RxKeyboard`の`Carthage`について**ということではなく**、
より一般的に**Carthageにおけるソースコードとバイナリーの関係性**について教えていただきたいと考えております。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RxKeyboardのリポジトリにはXcodeプロジェクトファイル（`*.xcodeproj`）が存在しないからです。

CarthageはCocoaPodsやSwift Package Managerと異なり、ビルド設定はXcodeプロジェクトの仕組みをそのまま利用します。
（CocoaPodsはPodspecの内容からXcodeプロジェクトファイルを生成してビルドするし、Swift Package Managerは標準ではXcodeプロジェクトファイルを使用しません。）

他のパッケージマネージャと異なり、Carthageは独自のビルドシステムを持たず、主な役割はパッケージ間の依存関係の解決のみを行います。

そのため、Xcodeプロジェクトファイル（`*.xcodeproj`）がリポジトリにコミットされてない以上、Carthageは依存関係を解決して、リポジトリをチェックアウトするところまではできますが、ビルドすることはできません。

それが、このプロジェクトではCarthageはバイナリインストールのみ、ソースコードからのビルドはサポートされていない理由です。